# set all links on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I've got a website set up that stores user input in a javascript variable, and I would like to set all links on the page (using javascript) to the href contained in each  tag, concatenated with the user input.

For example, if the user inputs "aaa" and then clicks a link to the home page, (with href="/home") then I would like the link to take the use to "/homeaaa"

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href]').click(function(){
    oldlink = $(this).attr("href");
    newlink = oldlink.concat(window.uservariable);
    document.links.href = newlink;
})
})
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href]').click(function(){
    oldlink = $(this).attr("href");
    newlink = oldlink.concat(window.uservariable);
    $(this).href = newlink;
})
})
```

but neither work. Neither change the href link when the user clicks it, to the href concatinated with the uservariable.

Comment: I have attempted it. I've tried many attempts

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: two of my attempts have now been included

Comment: Does your page load jQuery?

Comment: yes it loads jQuery

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).attr("href", newlink);`?

Comment: can you remove my down-vote now as I added examples? I've got it working now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code finds all a tags with attribute href and updates the values

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  x.forEach(function(item){
   var val = item.getAttribute("href");
    item.setAttribute("href", val + "aaa");
    console.log(item.getAttribute("href"))
        
  });
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV">
 <a href="/okety">Oekye</a>
  <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example" in div</h2>
  <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p> 
  <a href="/home">Oekye</a>
</div>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in DIV with class="example" (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The querySelectorAll() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Or on link click

```js
function myfunc2 (event,obj) { 
 event.preventDefault();
 var val = obj.getAttribute("href")
    obj.setAttribute("href", val + "aaa");
    console.log(obj.getAttribute("href"));
    //window.open("your attribut link")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV">
 <a href="/okety" onclick="myfunc2(event,this);">Oekye</a>
  <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example" in div</h2>
  <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p> 
  <a href="/home" onclick="myfunc2(event,this);">Oekye</a>
</div>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in DIV with class="example" (index 0).</p>



<p><strong>Note:</strong> The querySelectorAll() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yup, that works, when I add a $(document).ready( to the front and a closing ) to the end. Thanks